# Heroku deployment: JSON parse error in package.json despite being valid

Tags: javascript, json, heroku, mern

I am trying to deploy a mern app, but I get the following error, despite checking my package.json file myself and in multiple websites, what could be the issue here please?

---

```
> Compressing source files... done.
Building source:

-----> Node.js app detected
parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 12, column 3
 !     Unable to parse package.json


-----> Build failed

We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
https://help.heroku.com/

Love,
Heroku
```

---

HERE IS MY PACKAGE.JSON FILE

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index",
    "dev": "nodemon index",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-client && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": ["books"],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{
    "name": "backend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node index",
      "build": "cd client && npm run build",
      "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
      "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-client && npm run build"
    },
    "keywords": ["books"],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
      "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
      "cors": "^2.8.5",
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
      "mongoose": "^5.9.18"
    }
  }
```

Comment: it still gives the exact same error :/ here's the rest of the error if that might be helpful: ```To https://git.heroku.com/riterzappdemo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/riterzappdemo.git' ```

Comment: use this commands `git checkout -b masterbranch` and then `git push heroku masterbranch`

Comment: I did and here's what I got ```>git checkout -b masterbranch
Switched to a new branch 'masterbranch'
>git push heroku masterbranch
Enumerating objects: 38, done.
Counting objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
Writing objects: 100% (38/38), 177.20 KiB | 864.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 38 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Pushed to non-master branch, skipping build.
To https://git.heroku.com/riterzappdemo.git
 * [new branch]      masterbranch -> masterbranch``` app is still not up.